# Struggling to place 2 Divs on the same line with Grid Template

Tags: css

Basically I am trying to recreate this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLl9T.jpg

But struggling on the LightBlue and Red section on putting them on the same line:

```
 .sidebar {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width:20%;
    min-height:100px; 
}
.content {
    background-color: red;
    width:80%;
    min-height:100px;
}
```

So far I have tried Flex, inline-block and changing the widths, but cannot seem to get them from not appearing under each other

Inmy container I have:

```
.container {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "navbar navbar navbar navbar"        
    "sidebar content"
    "footer footer footer footer"
}
```

Comment: You need to use `grid-area` with the classes `sidebar` and `content`

Comment: Ok, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below. Using `grid-area` for all relevant classes and `width` removed for `sidebar` and `content`.

```css
.navbar {
  grid-area: navbar;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-height: 100px;
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 100px;
  grid-area: content;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "navbar navbar navbar navbar" "sidebar content content content" "footer footer footer footer"
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">navbar</div>
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah perfect, I see where I went wrong as I was not defining the Grid Area in each class, I was assuming the container class was handling that, thanks!